# How to deploy kafka on kubernetes on a remote linux server?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

how to deploy Kafka on Kubernetes on a remote machine? I Have deployed zookeeper pods successfully but Kafka pods keeps crashing(CrashLoopBackoff).

Below is the Kafka deployment and service yaml file I am using. I am also having confusion regarding the value of KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME in the file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  labels:
    name: kafka
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: kafka-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: kafka
    id: "0"
  type: LoadBalancer
```

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-broker0
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: kafka
        id: "0"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        id: "0"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: wurstmeister/kafka
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
          value: "30718"
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
          value: 192.168.1.240
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zoo1:2181
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "0"
        - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
          value: admintome-test:1:1
```

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.weave.works/blog/kafka-on-kubernetes-and-deploying-best-practice

kubectl describe pod gives

```
Name:             kafka-broker0-7cf7d4559-8frpn
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             prd-stg-185/172.0.0.1
Start Time:       Fri, 18 Nov 2022 13:05:12 +0400
Labels:           app=kafka
                  id=0
                  pod-template-hash=7cf7d4559
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 82fe4ebcf2b634bd29b3a2c95292f70493c3ad7cf3dc80369fc9e95be619da34
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.123.0/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.123.0/32
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.123.0
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.123.0
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/kafka-broker0-7cf7d4559
Containers:
  kafka:
    Container ID:   containerd://45c9ae210cbb6a5b29b87ea3bc3041f10c9132908fa4eba27a7a7f480b40c08e
    Image:          wurstmeister/kafka
    Image ID:       docker.io/wurstmeister/kafka@sha256:2d4bbf9cc83d9854d36582987da5f939fb9255fb128d18e3cf2c6ad825a32751
    Port:           9092/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Mon, 21 Nov 2022 09:36:45 +0400
      Finished:     Mon, 21 Nov 2022 09:37:08 +0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  752
    Environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT:       30718
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:  192.168.1.240
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:     zoo1:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID:             0
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS:         admintome-test:1:1
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-66qch (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-66qch:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                        From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                       ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff  6m16s (x17583 over 2d20h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: Did you use the same IP as in the tutorial? Guess you need to change it. First start trying 127.0.0.1.  Prerequesites can be found here https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/

Comment: Can you share output of kubectl describe pod kafka-broker0

Comment: You can't set 2 replicas with the same broker ID / advertised values

Comment: Strange that the blog is called "best practice", and it's not even functional deployment. Then goes on to recommend using Operators instead of rolling your own services

Comment: @OneCricketeer do you have any other tutorial recommendations that might be helpful?

Comment: The Strimzi site linked below is the first place I point people. Btw, I think your crash logs got cut-off in the question, and probably tells you what the real problem is

Answer (score 4):

For deploying Kafka on a Kubernetes cluster I would highly recommend using one of these options:

- [Bitnami's kafka helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/kafka)
- [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html)

Both options will be much easier than "manually" creating and managing the deployment.

As for the security part of the attached tutorial, I suggest taking a look at the [Otterize intents operator](https://github.com/otterize/intents-operator/) or the [Strimzi user operator](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/configuring.html#assembly-using-the-user-operator-str).